# WPF Toolkit - CheckComboBox

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm using the CheckComboBox from WPF Toolkit framework in my project and it works fine in VS 2010. However when running my program outside of VS, the view where the CheckComboBox is used, is not showing.

Before i manage to get it to work by adding 'using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit' in the xaml.cs file but this somehow doesn't work anymore.

**EDIT:**

I've added the Framework using NuGet so all the required dependencies should exist.

About the info on crash, not sure how to get this outside of VS. I've tried running the debug version but no crash info showing up.

Comment: make sure you have all the dependencies (wpf tookit dlls), copy them to the bin directory and try again.

Comment: BTW, "My program crashes, why?" is not  an answerable question, you should provide details on the crash -error message, error code, reproduce steps, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753790/how-to-prevent-a-combobox-from-closing-after-a-selection-is-clicked/27777222#27777222  this is same  control.