# How do I achieve multi selection in a combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, combobox

I am new to WPF, I am looking for a dropdown with checkbox to select multiple values. The source to the drop down would be from a list (list).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157744/multi-select-combobox-with-checkbox-generic-control-in-wpf

Answer (score 6):

Use WPF Extended Tookit. It may helps you
[image]

Here is the link: [WPF Toolkit CheckComboBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox)

**Usage**

```
 <xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="_combo" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="Color"
                     ValueMemberPath="Level"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
                     SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
```

Comment: @Mohamed Thanks for Update

Comment: I tried this as per the instruction, But option "SelectedItems" not available.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItems is read only, to get selected items IList.

```
 <xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="_combo" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="Color"
                     ValueMemberPath="Level"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
                     SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedItems}"
```

...but its tricky. SelectedItemsOverride should be ObservableCollection with get; set; and base on ItemSource.